# C# Implementing Auto-Scroll in a ListView while Drag & Dropping

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop, scroll

How do I implement Auto-Scrolling (e.g. the ListView scrolls when you near the top or bottom) in a Winforms ListView? I've hunted around on google with little luck. I can't believe this doesn't work out of the box!
Thanks in advance
Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrolling can be accomplished with the [ListViewItem.EnsureVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.ensurevisible(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
You need to determine if the item you are currently dragging over is at the visible boundary of the list view and is not the first/last.

```
private static void RevealMoreItems(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var listView = (ListView)sender;

    var point = listView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    var item = listView.GetItemAt(point.X, point.Y);
    if (item == null)
        return;

    var index = item.Index;
    var maxIndex = listView.Items.Count;
    var scrollZoneHeight = listView.Font.Height;

    if (index > 0 && point.Y < scrollZoneHeight)
    {
        listView.Items[index - 1].EnsureVisible();
    }
    else if (index < maxIndex && point.Y > listView.Height - scrollZoneHeight)
    {
        listView.Items[index + 1].EnsureVisible();
    }
}
```

Then wire this method to the DragOver event.

```
targetListView.DragOver += RevealMoreItems;

targetListView.DragOver += (sender, e) =>
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
};
```

Comment: Once you get a non-null item, you can call always item.EnsureVisible(). If the scroll is required it will do it and otherwise it will do nothing.

Comment: I don't get it. The idea here is an InsureVisible call for an item next to the one you are dragging over.

Comment: You can use item.EnsureVisible() after checking that item is not null and avoid getting index, maxIndex, scrollZoneHeight, etc. The user must drag a little more over the top or bottom edge, but it works. If you want the user getting the scrolling just hovering over the first or last item, then yes, your code is perfect.

Comment: Two corrections. var maxIndex = listView.Items.Count - 1 to avoid crashing at the last item when scrolling down and var scrollZoneHeight = listView.Font.Height * 2 to enlarge the range where scrolling begins. Then thumbs up.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for the link (http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/listviewdragdropscroll.html), I C#ised it

```
class ListViewBase:ListView
{
    private Timer tmrLVScroll;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
    private int mintScrollDirection;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    const int WM_VSCROLL = 277; // Vertical scroll
    const int SB_LINEUP = 0; // Scrolls one line up
    const int SB_LINEDOWN = 1; // Scrolls one line down

    public ListViewBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.tmrLVScroll = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tmrLVScroll
        // 
        this.tmrLVScroll.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.tmrLVScroll_Tick);
        // 
        // ListViewBase
        // 
        this.DragOver += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.ListViewBase_DragOver);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    protected void ListViewBase_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point position = PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        if (position.Y <= (Font.Height / 2))
        {
            // getting close to top, ensure previous item is visible
            mintScrollDirection = SB_LINEUP;
            tmrLVScroll.Enabled = true;
        }else if (position.Y >= ClientSize.Height - Font.Height / 2)
        { 
            // getting close to bottom, ensure next item is visible
            mintScrollDirection = SB_LINEDOWN;
            tmrLVScroll.Enabled = true;
        }else{
            tmrLVScroll.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void tmrLVScroll_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)mintScrollDirection, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer by George Polevoy is much simpler than this

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net). It does this stuff. You can read the code and use that if you don't want to use the ObjectListView itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for future googlers: to get this working on more complex controls (such as DataGridView), see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567809/how-to-autoscroll-a-datagridview-during-drag-and-drop).