# How to continue the scroll during drag and drop in WinForms?

Tags: c#, listview, graphics, windows-forms-designer

I have a ListView where I can move elements inside of it. When I have many elements you have to scroll the ListView but, if you are dragging and Item you can't scroll obviously.

Is there a way to do it automatically, like when you are "highlighting" a long text in Word or Chrome, where the page scroll automatically?

Comment: [C# Implementing Auto-Scroll in a ListView while Drag & Dropping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/660663/14171304).